# In a product database, How to calculate pricechange from two periods, and group by category

Tags: mysql, sql, percentage

hi have a product database which the price is changing every month (period) - I want to show the price-change in percent, grouped by category. The schema is something like this: id, name, category, price, period. (The period is YYYY-MM)

A rows could be:

```
123, "Chair" , "Furniture", 123 , 2013-05  -- for may
123, "Chair" , "Furniture", 110 , 2013-06  -- for june
```

Is it possible in a SQL-query to calculate the percentage difference for each product for each  month? And at the same time group categories together?

Comment: Are you using SQL Server? PostgreSQL? MySQL?

Comment: It would be nice if you add sample output for your data

Comment: Hi, I'm using mySQL - sample output:
Chair, Furniture -23.5%
Table, Furniture -10,2%
Shelf, Furniture -8,0%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The challenge in this sort of query is finding the previous period.  Here is one approach:

```
select p.*,
       (p.price - 
        (select p2.price
         from product p2
         where p2.id = p.id and p2.period < p.period
         order by period desc
         limit 1
        ) - 1
       ) * 100 as PercentageChange
from product p
order by category;
```

It uses a correlated subquery and it makes the assumption that there is a price by every month.  By "group categories together", I assume you mean to sort by the category.  (Aggregating by the category would lose the information about each product.)

Note that the above syntax could vary by database.  Different databases have different way of limiting the results to one row.